# lxd (ubuntu 16.10) container mac address

Tags: ubuntu, containers, lxc, lxd

I am running the latest Ubuntu (16.10) with LXD containers. Containers are configured with bridged networking, and they receive their own IP addresses from the DHCP server. I have configured them with the following:

lxc profile device add default eth0 nic nictype=bridged parent=br0

lxc network attach br0

Now, I need to set hardware addresses (MAC) manually for each of the containers, so their corresponding static IPs never change. However, I am having a hard time of doing so with lxc. Do I just set them in the corresponding /etc/network/interfaces, or is there a better (lxd/lxc) way of doing it?

Answer (score 8):

Each container will keep the same MAC address as it was at first launch time. To get its value:

```
lxc config show container_name
  or, more precise
lxc config get container_name volatile.NIC_NAME.hwaddr
```

This is not like in case of pure lxc when you had to manually set it in /var/lib/lxc/container_name/config.

But, if you really need to use your own set of MAC addresses(assuming eth0 is nic for container):

```
lxc config set container_name volatile.eth0.hwaddr yo:ur:ma:ca:dd:ress
```

Comment: “Pure lxc”? Is that lxc without lxd? Do you know if this is still the case with the latest version?

Comment: @KenSharp The command `lxc` indicates that it's for LXC 2.x and above (i.e. with LXD). LXC 1.x uses `lxc-*` commands.

Comment: Can this be set as a default address? For example, if I want to change the hwaddr for all new containers to 12:34:56:xx:xx:xx

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me on Centos 7.8. I think this is a solution that is distro-agnostic and thus likely most resilient.

In the container directory ( /var/lib/lxc/<container_name> ) edit the config file as follows:

```
    Template used to create this container: /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download
    # Parameters passed to the template: 
    # For additional config options, please look at lxc.container.conf(5)
    # Distribution configuration
    lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf
    lxc.arch = linux64
    # Container specific configuration
    lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/web0/rootfs
    lxc.utsname = web0
    # Network configuration
    lxc.network.type = veth
    lxc.network.flags = up
    lxc.network.link = virbr0
    **lxc.network.hwaddr = 6a:d4:d2:a7:9b:4e**
```

Note the last line. This is what I added - and that seems to maintain the MAC address constant.

Answer (score 1):

```
lxc config device override <instance name> eth0 hwaddr=00:11:22:aa:bb:cc
```

> The override command copies the NIC config from the profile into the instance and then modifies the config key(s) you provide.

via [Thomas Parrott](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/howto-add-hwaddr-to-nic-created-with-profile/9714/2?u=joshenders)